# Apache Kafka: Exception causing close of session <xx> due to java.io.IOException: Unreasonable length

Tags: apache-kafka

Apache Kafka 0.9.0

I'm getting the aforementioned exception in the zookeeper log when trying to perform a fetch via a consumer.  Here's how I'm creating the fetch request on the consumer:

```
kafka.api.FetchRequest req = new FetchRequestBuilder().clientId(clientId)
                                                      .addFetch(topic, 0, 0L, 100)
                                                      .build();
FetchResponse fetchResponse = simpleConsumer.fetch(req);
```

I see a `java.io.EOFException` when the consumer performs the fetch.

Any thoughts??